# How to run powershell with elevated access

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges

Using Powershell normal mode, I want to stop and start tomcat using a script with elevated access.
Im able to achieve this successfully using below script.

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Stop-Service Tomcat9" -Verb RunAs
  exit
}
```

But I dont want it to ask for confirmation prompt to proceed. I even tried adding  `-Confirm:$false` after the stop-service command but it still prompting for confirmation.

Is there any way i can skip the Confirmation prompt?

Comment: Imagine for a second that a program _could_ forcibly skip the confirmation. What then would be the point of Windows implementing the confirmation in the first place? It's there to give the user control over elevation.

Comment: You can't skip a UAC prompt. You can however, set a scheduled task as one of the available workarounds

Comment: You can skip confirmation by changing the service ACL to allow non-elevated users to start and stop the service (using `sc.exe sdset`). Obviously, though, this 1) requires elevated access itself, albeit just once and 2) would be permanent for all users, not just this particular script. A slightly more secure setup would be granting the permission to a group and making people members of this group as required.